# How find the button which was pressed in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to build a function that shows x widget in the coordinates of the button that triggered it but I don't know to how know which button was pressed. This it's the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(371, 165)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(26, 63, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(111, 63, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(196, 64, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 371, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button 3"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.functionButton)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.functionButton)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.functionButton)

    def functionButton(self):
        print("Function button")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The function does not do nothing for the moment, but how can I get the coordinates of the button that was pressed in that function for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the function is always called by a clicked button, you can use [`self.sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the object that sent the signal, and map the widget's top left (an empty QPoint) to the parent.

```
    def functionButton(self):
       button = self.sender()
       print(button.mapTo(self, QtCore.QPoint()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't have support for it directly. But you can accomplish it via lambdas.

```
self.push_button.connect.click(lambda: some_function(self.push_button))
```

This will call the function `some_function` and pass in the parameter `self.push_button`.

[Here's a nice little tutorial on it with a full example.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qpushbutton_widget.htm)